# Use SQLite to create table failed

Tags: java, database, sqlite

My project is Java Swing, and it needs a table, so I try to use SQLite.
And when I use SQLite, it can create a connection but when create table it failed. Please teach me, thanks in advance.

```
public class SqliteMethod {
private Connection conn;

private static String Create_Table = "create table if not exists table_message("
        + "_id integer primary key autoincrement," 
        + "name varchar(50)," 
        + "input_id varchar(50),"
        + "picture blob," 
        + "template blob"
        + ")";

public SqliteMethod() {
    try {

        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:scanner.db");

        Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
        if (!stat.execute(Create_Table))
            System.out.println("create table failed");
        stat.close();
        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The `conn` is not `null`, but when it go to create table, it failed

```
if (!stat.execute(Create_Table))
    System.out.println("create table failed");
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Swing, and *"please teache me"* SO is not a tutoring service.

Comment: you forget the stat.executeUpdate(create_table);

Comment: As i remember, Sqlite does not have varchar, it has got TEXT instead.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute(java.lang.String)) says:

> **Returns:**
>   `true` if the first result is a `ResultSet` object; `false` if it is an update count or there are no results

This statement is not a SELECT query, so it does not return any data, so there is no error. (An error would result in an `SQLException`.)